# Faster way of using Sumifs()

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, sumifs

I have a weekly task where I need to update a report (currently just over 50K rows) which is growing by around 500 rows every week. After the new data is added manually, I run the code below to do a `Sumifs()` to summarize the data.

The data structure is: columns A to C are the criteria columns (numeric-alpha-numeric), column D has the quantity to sum (whole numbers). The data is contiguous. My macro puts the `Sumifs()` formula into column E – overwriting what’s there.

My question is: can this task be done quicker? It currently takes me just over a minute to run the macro, but this gets longer as the data grows.

There’s a lot on this site about using Arrays to do tasks more quickly, but none of the examples make much sense to me and I would prefer not to use them if possible.

```
Sub MySumIfs()
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Sheet1.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

With Sheet1.Range("E2:E" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=sumifs(R2C4:R" & LastRow & "C4, R2C1:R" & LastRow & "C1, RC1, R2C2:R" & LastRow & "C2, RC2, R2C3:R" & LastRow & "C3, RC3)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: _but none of the examples make much sense to me (due to my own ignorance)_ : surely this is a learning opportunity then...

Comment: As you have already noted there is a lot of info on SO about using Arrays to speed up code.  Start with that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's another way:

EDIT - updated to add "averageifs" and "sumifs" to my initial (mistaken) "countifs" version...

```vb
Sub SetupDummyData()
    Const NUM As Long = 100001
    Range("A1:E1").Value = Array("A_Header", "B_Header", "C_Header", "Value", "ResultHere")
    Range("A2:A" & NUM).Formula = "=""A#"" & round(RAND()*10,0)"
    Range("B2:B" & NUM).Formula = "=""B#"" & round(RAND()*10,0)"
    Range("C2:C" & NUM).Formula = "=""C#"" & round(RAND()*10,0)"
    Range("D2:D" & NUM).Formula = "=round(RAND()*100,1)"
    
    Range("A2:D" & NUM).Value = Range("A2:D" & NUM).Value
End Sub


Sub Tester()
    
    Dim arr, ws, rng As Range, keyCols, valueCol As Long, destCol As Long, i As Long, frm As String, sep As String
    Dim t, dict, arrOut(), arrValues(), v, tmp, n As Long
    
    keyCols = Array(1, 2, 3)  'these columns form the composite key
    valueCol = 4              'column with values (for sum)
    destCol = 5               'destination for calculated values
    
    t = Timer
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    n = rng.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(n) 'exclude headers
    
    'build the formula to create the row "key"
    For i = 0 To UBound(keyCols)
        frm = frm & sep & rng.Columns(keyCols(i)).Address
        sep = "&""|""&"
    Next i
    arr = ws.Evaluate(frm)  'get an array of composite keys by evaluating the formula
    arrValues = rng.Columns(valueCol).Value  'values to be summed
    ReDim arrOut(1 To n, 1 To 1)             'this is for the results
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'first loop over the array counts the keys
    For i = 1 To n
        v = arr(i, 1)
        If Not dict.exists(v) Then dict(v) = Array(0, 0) 'count, sum
        tmp = dict(v) 'can't modify an array stored in a dictionary - pull it out first
        tmp(0) = tmp(0) + 1                 'increment count
        tmp(1) = tmp(1) + arrValues(i, 1)   'increment sum
        dict(v) = tmp                       'return the modified array
    Next i
    
    'second loop populates the output array from the dictionary
    For i = 1 To n
        arrOut(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1))(1)                       'sumifs
        'arrOut(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1))(0)                      'countifs
        'arrOut(i, 1) = dict(arr(i, 1))(1) / dict(arr(i, 1))(0) 'averageifs
    Next i
    'populate the results
    rng.Columns(destCol).Value = arrOut
    
    Debug.Print "Checked " & n & " rows in " & Timer - t & " secs"

End Sub
```

Comment: oops I guess I didn't read the question (or the title...) closely enough.  Will fix later...

Comment: @kevin9999 - thanks for the comment. I feel bad about "stealing" your checkmark.  Just can't resists a "speed this up" challenge...

Comment: You’re welcome Tim, and well deserved – I was simply happy to learn something new.  Sadly, Arrays are a penny that’s yet to drop for me.  If you’re game for another “speed this up” challenge, please check out my one and only question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64748492/vlookup-alternative-using-arrays I tested all the answers using 50K lookup values across 200K rows (2 cols) and they all came in at between 7 to 9 seconds (except the first that took forever). Best regards.

Comment: Tim, all I used was `=RANDBETWEEN(1,500)` and `.value = .value` for the 50K values to lookup, as well as the 2 columns (200k rows) of values to search & return.  It was really just to test the speed of all the answers given :)

Comment: This is great. One question I have - how could we achieve this if data was in different sheet and result intended was to be in another sheet (also columns not in same order as data sheet columns). Thanks

Comment: @Manny - well you'd need to make the necessary adjustments?  That's all I can say really - there's nothing about this method which means the inputs and outputs need to be on the same sheet. or even in the same workbook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not that great with VBA. Could you demonstrate a multi sheet scenario (data in one sheet and result in another)? I tried this with Multi-sheet and I couldn't do it. Would be awesome if you could help? Thanks

Comment: this is what i added to your code.    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    n = rng.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(n) 'exclude headers
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set rng2 = ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    n2 = rng2.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rng2 = rng2.Offset(1, 0).Resize(n2) 'exclude headers

Comment: While it pasted the results in Sheet2, the sumifs weren't using the column values in Sheet2 and rather using them from Sheet1 only. How do I change it? Thanks

Comment: Please post a new question and include your full code and a link to this post.  I will take a look.  Can't easily review code posted in a comment.

Comment: Can we have a similar code that extracts the composite keys in a column (the unique values) and its total in another column?