# Tips to speed up SUMIF

Tags: excel, vba, performance, optimization

I have a Excel Macro that calculates the following

```
Range("P2").Formula = "=SUMIF($B$2:B2,B2,$O$2:O2)*O2"
Range("P2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & LastRowData)
Range("P2:P" & LastRowData).Calculate
```

```
    In Column B is a list of names (with multiple rows with the same name)
    In Column O is a number (either 0 or 1)
```

Essentially I am trying to increment a column (starting with 1) to compute their next available appointment (where column O is if I should even consider that row in the computation).

I run this daily and the above steps takes easily over 15 minutes to run, as my files are very large (in terms of rows, between 100,000 and 200,000 rows)

Is there any way to speed this up? I am intermediate at best with Excel Macros.

Comment: You can try an IF() instead of Multiplying: `"=IF(O2,SUMIF($B$2:B2,B2,$O$2:O2),0)"`  which should return the same thing but cut out doing a sumif on any that are not needed.

Comment: But the quickest would be to load the whole into a variant array, iterate that array and use a dictionary to get the list of the people adding to the item each time the name is encountered.  Then loop array again and create an output array that puts the result from the dictionary.

Comment: @ScottCraner - do you have code for this? I am not sure how

Comment: If  you can sort column B, your formula could check if the current row in B is the same as the row above, and if so use the above cell in column P instead of recalculating it. (this assumes that a given name in B always has the same value in col O)

Comment: @Rory A given name in B does not always have the same value in O

Comment: Then can you sort on both B and O?

Comment: @Rory - I am sorted on Name, Date and Time of Appt - Column O has a check if the appointment is a valid one to count.  I essentially need to increment a counter for each row that the provider name is the same as the one above AND Column O is = 1. When the name changes in Column B, i need to reset the counter to 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Faster way of using Sumifs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs)

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me of a similar SUMIFS() issue I had to deal with.  The following code does not use arrays (which would probably be faster still) but I tested it on 200K rows of data & it completed between 6 – 8 seconds.

It assumes columns Q & R are available for use as ‘helper’ columns, and that all the action takes place on sheet 1 of your file.  I’ve provided both a ‘normal’ SUMIF() calculation, as well as an option to multiply by column O as per your apparent calculation.  Comment out whichever is not used.  Let me know how it goes.

```
Option Explicit
Sub QuickerSumif()
Dim LastRow As Long, a As Double
a = Timer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

'Get the last row based on the names column (B)
LastRow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

'Store the original order
With Sheet1.Range("R2:R" & LastRow)
    .Formula = "=Row()"
    .Value = .Value
End With

'Sort the data by names (column B)
Sheet1.Columns("A:R").Sort Key1:=Sheet1.Range("B2"), _
order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Sum the 1/0 values for each name with a simple IF() formula
With Sheet1.Range("P2:P" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2=R[-1]C2,RC15+R[-1]C16,RC15)"        '<~~ 'normal' SUMIF()
    '.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2=R[-1]C2,RC15+R[-1]C16,RC15)*RC15"   '<~~ your formula
    .Value = .Value
End With

'Sort again by names and 'accumulated' sum
Sheet1.Columns("A:R").Sort Key1:=Sheet1.Range("B2"), order1:=xlDescending, _
Key2:=Sheet1.Range("P2"), order2:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes

'Get the max accumulated sum for each name with a simple IF() formula
With Sheet1.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow)
    .FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC2=R[-1]C2,R[-1]C17,RC16)"
        .Value = .Value
End With

'Replace column P data with the SUMIF equivalent
Sheet1.Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Value = Sheet1.Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Value

'Restore the original order
Sheet1.Columns("A:R").Sort Key1:=Sheet1.Range("R2"), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

'Delete the 2 x helper columns
Sheet1.Range("Q:R").EntireColumn.Delete

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Msgbox Timer – a
End Sub
```