# dictionary and total sum of items for each key from one workbook and write to other workbook

Tags: vba

with VBA dictionary, I would like to be able to search for the matching key from my workbook 2 to workbook 1 and if the match is found in workbook 1, get and sum the amount value of the key items and write back the answer in workbook 2.

I can do the same sheet match and write it in the same sheet but can't do the sum and writing the result in another workbook. please assist.

[Workbook1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2K6Xs.png)

[Workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd9Dt.png)

Comment: You can do this with SumIf()

Comment: I can but it won't be as fast and effective as my rows are getting large and could be in hundreds of thousands.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64940481#64940481

Comment: Hi Tim, Sorry for the late reply. my challenge is how to write the result in another workbook where I have the keys. so far my way is I Copy the entire result to another workbook then I use index match to match the value of each key.

Comment: Another workbook or worksheet doesn't really make any difference to the core of the problem.  There are lots of example here of how to work with multiple worksheets and workbooks.