# Excel/VBA not responding after one sheet reaches ~60,000 rows

Tags: vba, excel-2016

New to VBA but have been working on a project to help balance our system faster. Code has been working great since it was implemented on 5/1 but has become very sluggish as more data is added each day. Now, on the 21st, the code runs for 30+ minutes to finish.

Code spans across 5 sheets with the maximum # of columns being 17 and the maximum number of rows will continue to grow up to around 150,000 but this is only an estimation. Any help in improving performance would be greatly appreciated!

```vb
Sub Recalculate_Formulas_Section1and2()
   
'Disables settings to speed up code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = False
    
'Test if the value in cell A2 of the Daily Billing Reports is blank/empty
   If IsEmpty(Sheets("Daily Billing Reports").Range("A2").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(Sheets("R301 - All Categories").Range("A2").Value) = True Then
      MsgBox "Import Daily Billing Report and R301 Data to Calculate Section 1 and 2 Variances"
      
      Else
    
'Code to insert validation formulas in Invoice Balancing Template
    Dim lastRowBilling As Long, lastRowR301 As Long, lastRowR301F2 As Long, lastRowBSD As Long, lastRowChanges As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range, rng3 As Range, rng4 As Range, rng5 As Range, rng6 As Range, rng7 As Range, rng8 As Range, rng9 As Range
    Dim rng10 As Range, rng11 As Range, rng12 As Range, rng13 As Range, rng14 As Range, rng15 As Range

    'Determine Last Row in Column B (Daily Billing Reports Tab)
    With Worksheets("Daily Billing Reports")
        lastRowBilling = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    'Determine Last Row in Column B (R301F Today-1 Tab)
    With Worksheets("R301F-All Categories (Today-1)")
        lastRowR301F2 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    
    'Determine Last Row in Column B (Booked Same Day Tab)
    With Worksheets("R301 - Booked Same Day")
        lastRowBSD = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    'Determine Last Row in Column B (Changes Tab)
    With Worksheets("Changes")
        lastRowChanges = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("R301 - All Categories")
        'Determine last Row in Column B (R301 - All Categories Tab)
        lastRowR301 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Set rng1 = .Range("I2:I" & lastRowR301) 'Sums Daily Billing Report revenue and pastes formula value in respective row for column I
        rng1.Formula = "=SUMIFS('Daily Billing Reports'!$N$2:$N$" & lastRowBilling & ",'Daily Billing Reports'!$B$2:$B$" & lastRowBilling & ",D2,'Daily Billing Reports'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowBilling & ",G2)"

        Set rng2 = rng1.Offset(0, 1) 'Shows the variance between Daily Billing Report revenue and R301 - All Categories revenue
        rng2.Formula = "=ROUND(SUMIFS('R301 - All Categories'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301 & ",'R301 - All Categories'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301 & ",D2,'R301 - All Categories'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301 & ",G2)-I2,2)"

        Set rng9 = rng1.Offset(0, 2) 'Sums R301F-All Categories (Today-1) revenue - Changes
        rng9.Formula = "=SUMIFS('R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",D2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",G2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",A2)-SUMIFS('Changes'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRowChanges & ",'Changes'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowChanges & ",D2,'Changes'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowChanges & ",G2,'Changes'!$C$2:$C$" & lastRowChanges & ",A2,'Changes'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowChanges & ",""<=""&G2)"

        Set rng10 = rng1.Offset(0, 3) 'Shows the variance between Section 1 and Section 2 excluding any changes logged by accounting
        rng10.Formula = "=ROUND(SUMIFS('R301 - All Categories'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301 & ",'R301 - All Categories'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301 & ",D2,'R301 - All Categories'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301 & ",G2,'R301 - All Categories'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowR301 & ",A2)-K2,2)"

        Set rng12 = rng1.Offset(0, 4) 'Flags if Variance or Not. Used for Pivot Tables.
        rng12.Formula = "=IF(RC[-3]=0,""No"",""Yes"")"
            
        Set rng13 = rng1.Offset(0, 5) 'Flags if Variance or Not but excludes if Day isn't on the R301F-All Categories (Today-1) yet. Used for Pivot Tables.
        rng13.Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]=0,""No"",IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-7],'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!C[-7],1,FALSE),0)=0,""No"",""Yes""))"
        
        'Drags values entered into column I and N down to bottom of data set
        Range("I2:N" & lastRowR301).Value = Range("I2:N" & lastRowR301).Value
    End With

    With Worksheets("Daily Billing Reports")

        Set rng3 = .Range("U2:U" & lastRowBilling) 'Sums R301 - All Categories revenue
        rng3.Formula = "=SUMIFS('R301 - All Categories'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301 & ",'R301 - All Categories'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301 & ",B2,'R301 - All Categories'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301 & ",A2)"

        Set rng4 = rng3.Offset(0, 1) 'Shows the variance between R301 - All Categories revenue and Daily Billing Report revenue
        rng4.Formula = "=ROUND(SUMIFS('Daily Billing Reports'!$N$2:$N$" & lastRowBilling & ",'Daily Billing Reports'!$B$2:$B$" & lastRowBilling & ",B2,'Daily Billing Reports'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowBilling & ",A2)-U2,2)"
        
        Set rng11 = rng3.Offset(0, 2) 'Flags if Variance or Not. Used for Pivot Tables.
        rng11.Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]=0,""No"",""Yes"")"
        
        'Drags values entered into column U and W down to bottom of data set
        Range("U2:W" & lastRowBilling).Value = Range("U2:W" & lastRowBilling).Value
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("R301F-All Categories (Today-1)")

        Set rng5 = .Range("I2:I" & lastRowR301F2) 'Sums R301 - All Categories revenue + Booked Same Day revenue + Changes revenue
        rng5.Formula = "=SUMIFS('R301 - All Categories'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301 & ",'R301 - All Categories'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301 & ",D2,'R301 - All Categories'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301 & ",G2,'R301 - All Categories'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowR301 & ",A2)+SUMIFS('R301 - Booked Same Day'!$I$2:$I$" & lastRowBSD & ",'R301 - Booked Same Day'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowBSD & ",D2,'R301 - Booked Same Day'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowBSD & ",G2,'R301 - Booked Same Day'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowBSD & ",A2)+SUMIFS('Changes'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRowChanges & ",'Changes'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowChanges & ",D2,'Changes'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowChanges & ",G2,'Changes'!$C$2:$C$" & lastRowChanges & ",A2,'Changes'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowChanges & ",""<=""&G2)"

        Set rng6 = rng5.Offset(0, 1) 'Shows the variance between R301F-All Categories (Today-1) revenue + Booked Same Day + Changes and R301 - All Categories
        rng6.Formula = "=ROUND(SUMIFS('R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",D2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",G2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",A2)-I2,2)"
        
        Set rng14 = rng6.Offset(0, 1) 'Flags if Variance or Not. Used for Pivot Tables.
        rng14.Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]=0,""No"",""Yes"")"

        'Drags values entered into column I and K down to bottom of data set
        Range("I2:K" & lastRowR301F2).Value = Range("I2:K" & lastRowR301F2).Value
    End With
        
    With Worksheets("R301 - Booked Same Day")
    If IsEmpty(Sheets("R301 - Booked Same Day").Range("A2").Value) = True Then

    Else
        Set rng7 = .Range("J2:J" & lastRowBSD) 'Sums R301F-All Categories (Today-1) revenue + Changes revenue
        rng7.Formula = "=SUMIFS('R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$H$2:$H$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",D2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",H2,'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowR301F2 & ",A2)+SUMIFS('Changes'!$E$2:$E$" & lastRowChanges & ",'Changes'!$D$2:$D$" & lastRowChanges & ",D2,'Changes'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowChanges & ",H2,'Changes'!$C$2:$C$" & lastRowChanges & ",A2,'Changes'!$G$2:$G$" & lastRowChanges & ",""<=""&G2)"

        Set rng8 = rng7.Offset(0, 1) 'Shows the variance between Booked Same Day revenue + Changes and
        rng8.Formula = "=ROUND(I2-J2,2)"
        
        Set rng15 = rng7.Offset(0, 2) 'Flags if Variance or Not. Used for Pivot Tables.
        rng15.Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]=0,""No"",IF(IFNA(VLOOKUP(RC[-4],'R301F-All Categories (Today-1)'!C[-7],1,FALSE),0)=0,""No"",""Yes""))"

        'Drags values entered into column J and K down to bottom of data set
        Range("J2:L" & lastRowBSD).Value = Range("J2:L" & lastRowBSD).Value
    End If
    End With

'Refreshes Pivot Tables and Formulas after data is copied
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Calculate

'Select Section 1-3 Variances Tab of Invoice Balancing Workbook
    Sheets("Section 1-3 Variances").Select

'Enables settings once code is completed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    ActiveWorkbook.AutoSaveOn = True

'Pop up message after process completes
    MsgBox "Process Complete!"
    
End If

End Sub
```

***Edit 1:***
Tried code to create composite keys and then SUMIF one of my original formulas but the fourth With statement took an hour to execute. Any thoughts on how to speed the SUMIF formula up?

```
Sub Tester()
    
'Test if the value in cell A2 of the Daily Billing Reports is blank/empty
   If IsEmpty(Sheets("Daily Billing Reports").Range("A2").Value) = True Or IsEmpty(Sheets("R301 - All Categories").Range("A2").Value) = True Then
      MsgBox "Import Daily Billing Report and R301 Data to Calculate Section 1 Variances"
      
      Else
    
'Code to insert validation formulas in Invoice Balancing Template
  
    'Case 2 - temporary "key" column and SUMIF()
    t1 = Timer
    
    With Worksheets("Daily Billing Reports")
    
        'add a temporary "composite key" column to Daily Billing Reports sheet...
        With .Range("U2:U150000")
            .Formula = "=B2 & ""|"" & A2"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
    
    Debug.Print Timer - t1 '   <1 sec
    
    'Case 2 - temporary "key" column and SUMIF()
    t2 = Timer
    
    With Worksheets("R301 - All Categories")

        'add a temporary "composite key" column to R301 - All Categories sheet...
        With .Range("I2:I150000")
            .Formula = "=D2 & ""|"" & G2"
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    
        'use a SUMIF() on the key column
        With .Range("J2:J150000")
            .Formula = "=SUMIF('Daily Billing Reports'!U2:U150000,I2,'Daily Billing Reports'!N2:N150000)"
            .Value = .Value 'convert to values
        End With
    End With

    Debug.Print Timer - t2 '   About 1 hr
    
    End If
End Sub
```

***Edit 2:***
Also tried building this out in an array but unsure how to subtract arrR301Out from arrBillingOut and place in destination column 11. Would also prefer to place arrBillingOut in destColR301 of the R301 - All Categories sheet and arrR301Out in destColBilling of the Daily Billing Reports sheet if possible.

```
Sub Tester()

'Code to run Billing Report Values
    Dim arrBilling, wsBilling, rngBilling As Range, keyColsBilling, valueColBilling As Long, destColBilling As Long, iBilling As Long, frmBilling As String, sepBilling As String
    Dim tBilling, dictBilling, arrBillingOut(), arrBillingValues(), vBilling, tmpBilling, nBilling As Long

    keyColsBilling = Array(2, 1)  'these columns form the composite key
    valueColBilling = 14              'column with values (for sum)
    destColBilling = 22               'destination for calculated values
    
    tBilling = Timer
    
    Set wsBilling = Worksheets("Daily Billing Reports")
    Set rngBilling = wsBilling.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    nBilling = rngBilling.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rngBilling = rngBilling.Offset(1, 0).Resize(nBilling) 'exclude headers
    
    'build the formula to create the row "key"
    For iBilling = 0 To UBound(keyColsBilling)
        frmBilling = frmBilling & sepBilling & rngBilling.Columns(keyColsBilling(iBilling)).Address
        sepBilling = "&""|""&"
    Next iBilling
    arrBilling = wsBilling.Evaluate(frmBilling)  'get an array of composite keys by evaluating the formula
    arrBillingValues = rngBilling.Columns(valueColBilling).Value  'values to be summed
    ReDim arrBillingOut(1 To nBilling, 1 To 1)             'this is for the results
    
    Set dictBilling = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'first loop over the array counts the keys
    For iBilling = 1 To nBilling
        vBilling = arrBilling(iBilling, 1)
        If Not dictBilling.exists(vBilling) Then dictBilling(vBilling) = Array(0, 0) 'count, sum
        tmpBilling = dictBilling(vBilling) 'can't modify an array stored in a dictionary - pull it out first
        tmpBilling(0) = tmpBilling(0) + 1                 'increment count
        tmpBilling(1) = tmpBilling(1) + arrBillingValues(iBilling, 1)   'increment sum
        dictBilling(vBilling) = tmpBilling                       'return the modified array
    Next iBilling
    
    'second loop populates the output array from the dictionary
    For iBilling = 1 To nBilling
        arrBillingOut(iBilling, 1) = dictBilling(arrBilling(iBilling, 1))(1)  'sumifs
    Next iBilling
'    'populate the results
     rngBilling.Columns(destColBilling).Value = arrBillingOut

    Debug.Print "Checked " & nBilling & " rows in " & Timer - tBilling & " secs"

'Code to run R301 Values
    Dim arrR301, wsR301, rngR301 As Range, keyColsR301, valueColR301 As Long, destColR301 As Long, iR301 As Long, frmR301 As String, sepR301 As String
    Dim tR301, dictR301, arrR301Out(), arrR301Values(), vR301, tmpR301, nR301 As Long

    keyColsR301 = Array(4, 7)  'these columns form the composite key
    valueColR301 = 8              'column with values (for sum)
    destColR301 = 10              'destination for calculated values
    
    tR301 = Timer
    
    Set wsR301 = Worksheets("R301 - All Categories")
    Set rngR301 = wsR301.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    nR301 = rngR301.Rows.Count - 1
    Set rngR301 = rngR301.Offset(1, 0).Resize(nR301) 'exclude headers
    
    'build the formula to create the row "key"
    For iR301 = 0 To UBound(keyColsR301)
        frmR301 = frmR301 & sepR301 & rngR301.Columns(keyColsR301(iR301)).Address
        sepR301 = "&""|""&"
    Next iR301
    arrR301 = wsR301.Evaluate(frmR301)  'get an array of composite keys by evaluating the formula
    arrR301Values = rngR301.Columns(valueColR301).Value  'values to be summed
    ReDim arrR301Out(1 To nR301, 1 To 1)             'this is for the results
    
    Set dictR301 = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    'first loop over the array counts the keys
    For iR301 = 1 To nR301
        vR301 = arrR301(iR301, 1)
        If Not dictR301.exists(vR301) Then dictR301(vR301) = Array(0, 0) 'count, sum
        tmpR301 = dictR301(vR301) 'can't modify an array stored in a dictionary - pull it out first
        tmpR301(0) = tmpR301(0) + 1                 'increment count
        tmpR301(1) = tmpR301(1) + arrR301Values(iR301, 1)   'increment sum
        dictR301(vR301) = tmpR301                       'return the modified array
    Next iR301
    
    'second loop populates the output array from the dictionary
    For iR301 = 1 To nR301
        arrR301Out(iR301, 1) = dictR301(arrR301(iR301, 1))(1)  'sumifs
    Next iR301
    'populate the results
     rngR301.Columns(destColR301).Value = arrR301Out
       
End Sub
```

**Edit 3:** Modified Tim's code below but getting a Sub or Function not defined error for RowMap.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim t, data, map As Object

    Set ws = Worksheets("Test Daily Billing")
    Set wsR301 = Worksheets("Test R301")

    t = Timer

    data = ws.Range("A2:N40000").Value
    Set map = RowMap(data, Array(2, 1), 14) 'get a summed "map" of the source data
    
    Debug.Print "Built dict", Timer - t

    data = wsR301.Range("A2:H40000").Value
    wsR301.Range("H2:H40000").Value = GetResults(data, map, Array(4, 7)) ' Column H holds the sum value here

    Debug.Print "Done", Timer - t, vbLf

End Sub
```

Comment: Must be a typo, but looks like you're using R1C1-style formulas several times while writing to `.Formula`, e.g. `rng11.Formula = "=IF(RC[-1]=0,""No"",""Yes"")"`.

Comment: Also, this smells like you're (ab)using Excel as a database.

Comment: There's nothing striking. I suspect most of the time is spent on `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll`. Can you check that? Because it would mean that the problem is that the formulas are taking too much time.

Comment: @BigBen using excel as a balancing mechanism for a database. A new workbook is created each month. Would converting the R1C1-style formulas improve performance?

Comment: No that would not improve performance. It would be more appropriate to use `.FormulaR1C1` when writing R1C1-style formulas though, but the number of formulas is the real issue.

Comment: I agree with @assylias, you are creating many 100s of thousands sumifs,  SUMIFS are slow and using them that much is what is causing the issue.

Comment: @assylias removed `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` as well as `Calculate` and it's still locking up.

Comment: It looks like these per-date "All Categories" could also be coming from a database? If so, it looks like all these lookups and sumifs belong server-side, in a view. Alternatively, take your tables into a Power Query data model, and only load the final desired data set into Excel.

Comment: Might be faster to drop in some temporary "composite key" columns so you can use SUMIF() in place of SUMIFS() ?  That would likely cut your calculation time.

Comment: If you remove the line, the calculation still happens when you reenable the settings. Put a debug.Print with the time just before and just after to see how long it takes.

Comment: wouldn't using array's instead of formulas be much faster?

Comment: @assylias I will do this first thing Monday morning and report back.

Comment: Found the following post and started converting the SUMIFS to arrays but am stumped on how to convert the first SUMIFS which references another sheets values. Post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64939999#64939999



`Set rng1 = .Range("I2:I" & lastRowR301) 'Sums Daily Billing Report revenue and pastes formula value in respective row for column I
        rng1.Formula = "=SUMIFS('Daily Billing Reports'!$N$2:$N$" & lastRowBilling & ",'Daily Billing Reports'!$B$2:$B$" & lastRowBilling & ",D2,'Daily Billing Reports'!$A$2:$A$" & lastRowBilling & ",G2)"`

Comment: @TimWilliams apologies for any confusion. Still learning SO and VBA. Tried 2 of your solutions and added the code I tried to the original post. Edit 1 is the composite key but the SUMIF took about an hour to complete. Edit 2 is from a solution of yours I found on SO but unsure how to modify the array to create the output I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you able to share a copy of your file (suitably redacted) ?  It's difficult to work on a solution without the source data...  If Yes I will share my email here

Comment: Yes I can. Working on redacting info now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a re-working of a previous answer in another question - it's a faster alternative to SUMIFS() based on using a dictionary to map composite keys (from specified columns) to a summed value from another specified column in the source data.  That "map" can then be applied to a second set of data in order to add the sums there based on matched row "key".

`Tester` shows how to apply it (long-form and as a one-liner).  Rest of the code is re-usable functions.

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim t, data, map As Object

    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    t = Timer

    data = ws.Range("A2:D100000").Value
    Set map = RowMap(data, Array(1, 2, 3), 4) 'get a summed "map" of the source data

    Debug.Print "Built dict", Timer - t

    data = ws.Range("J2:L1000").Value
    ws.Range("M2:M1000").Value = GetResults(data, map, Array(1, 2, 3))

    Debug.Print "Done", Timer - t, vbLf
    
    'as a one-liner:
    ws.Range("N2:N1000").Value = GetResults(ws.Range("J2:L1000").Value, _
                                         RowMap(ws.Range("A2:D100000").Value, Array(1, 2, 3), 4), _
                                         Array(1, 2, 3))
    
End Sub

'########## below here is all re-usable code..... ###########

'Pass in a dataset, a "map" (dictionary with row "keys" and sums)
'  and an array of column numbers in data to use as composite key
' Return a single-column array with same # of rows as `data`
Function GetResults(data, map, arrKeyCols)
    Dim calcs, r As Long, k
    ReDim calcs(1 To UBound(data, 1), 1 To 1)
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        k = RowKey(data, r, arrKeyCols)
        If map.exists(k) Then calcs(r, 1) = map(k)
    Next r
    GetResults = calcs
End Function

'Pass in a data array, an array of column numbers in data to use as composite key,
' and a column number to sum based on the key
' Return a dictionary mapping keys to sums
Function RowMap(data, arrKeyCols, valueCol) As Object 'dictionary
    Dim dict As Object, k As String, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For r = LBound(data) To UBound(data)
        k = RowKey(data, r, arrKeyCols)'EDIT not Array(1, 2, 3)
        dict(k) = dict(k) + data(r, valueCol)
    Next r
    Set RowMap = dict
End Function

'Create a composite key from columns in arrKeyCols
Function RowKey(data, rowNum, arrKeyCols) As String
    Dim rv, i, sep
    For i = LBound(arrKeyCols) To UBound(arrKeyCols)
        rv = rv & sep & data(rowNum, arrKeyCols(i))
        sep = "~~"
    Next i
    RowKey = rv
End Function
```

Comment: if the values to create the composite key are located in columns A and B would `data = ws.Range("A2:B100000").Value` be correct or should this expand to the column where my Sum value is? How would I skip a column if my composite key is a combination of G then D?

Will keep looking through this

Comment: When calling RowMap the passed `data` array needs to include all the key columns and the column to be summed.  Column numbers are relative to the array (so for example if you pass in an array from A:G then keyColumns might be Array(7, 4) (G and D,  though the order doesn't really matter)and your value column might be 3 (C)

Comment: Got it, thank you Tim. Could you clarify what the code between Debug.Print is actually doing?

Comment: The code between the two Debug.Print statements is mapping the summed values to the second range (based on matched "key" columns).  To clarify - that "one-liner" is the equivalent of all of the code above it - it will produce the same results.

Comment: getting a Sub or Function not defined error for RowMap. Included the modified code in Edit 3 above. The problem I'm having is the information is on 2 sheets so I added wsR301 for the second sheet. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you include the RowMap function?

Comment: Just noticed a typo in RowMap - make sure to fix that in your copy