# How to make two Excel macro codes run faster?

Tags: excel, vba

I created code from several codes. I have read I can use arrays and turn off several Excel functions to make it significantly faster, but am not experienced enough to implement it.

The code works with a smaller number of rows, but is slow when I use it for my sheets, which have - workbook 1- 70000 rows, workbook 2- 30000 rows.

This code deletes unwanted columns, adds new ones, arranges them (in the exportfile), and then moves onto the slow part to compare two workbooks and paste new info rows into masterworkbook from exportfile.

**UPDATED**
I took away unnecessary parts of the code that function well and left the part which is slow. I must emphasize that it does not crash, but rather is slow, which I assume at either matching and giving outputs of true or false or copying and pasting the selected rows. How do I make these two parts work more efficiently?

```vb
Sub Update()

    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim recRow As Long
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim fCell As Range
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set DstFile = Workbooks("ExtractFile.xlsm")
    Set wsSource = Workbooks("ExtractFile.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Workbook.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    recRow = 1
    
    With wsSource
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To lastRow
            'See if item is in Master sheet
            **Set fCell = wsDest.Range("A:A").Find(what:=.Cells(i, "A").Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)**
            
            If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
                'Record is already in master sheet
                recRow = fCell.Row
            Else
                'Need to move this to master sheet after last found record
                **.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Copy
                wsDest.Cells(recRow + 1, "A").EntireRow.Insert
                recRow = recRow + 1**
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    'Clean up
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    DstFile.Save
    DstFile.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I voted to close as this needs some focus.  There are several things going on in this post, some of which may be more appropriate for CodeReview, and others that would take up multiple questions on StackOverflow.  Rewriting the entirety of your code is a bit out of the scope for this site, so the request for more focus would be (to me) narrowing this down to a few specific bullet points and providing more information on the crash... does it crash at a specific line every time, does it crash from the start, is it always on a specific column/row?  More detail may help.

Comment: Looking at your delete selection, you can `union()` those ranges and delete in a single event, which can all be looped through.  The speed would increase, but as written this should not cause a crash.

Comment: You have references to sheets/books that you later `set`, meaning they would be more helpful to be set earlier in the code.  You also have several un-qualified ranges, e.g., `Columns(27).EntireColumn.Delete` rather than `wsDest.Columns(27).EntireColumn.Delete`.  Avoid `Activate/Select` wherever possible.

Comment: When you find codes and you don't know how to explain what they do (*"moves onto slow part to compare two workbooks"* doesn't quite do it), at least share the links to the original posts and credit the authors.

Comment: I would happily credit the authors, but unfortunately, I do not have these links anymore, as for me, a person who just recently started vba I had to really dig through many sites to stick together pieces of code to make it do what i want, now its just slow:) as saying goes, why create a wheel when its already created, modify it and use it for your purpose! and ofc credit matters, but... done a lot of digging

Comment: Using `Find()` is much slower than some other approaches such as using `Match()` or creating a "map" of values and row numbers using a Scripting Dictionary (similar to "RowMap" here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/67693969/478884).  Also suspect a row `Insert` may be slower than appending the row at the next empty row in the destination sheet.

Comment: Voted to re-open; thank you for cleaning up the question and getting to a more focused goal.

Comment: Consider using Power Query (Data tab > Get & Transform) for this task. It will likely be much quicker to make and a lot faster to run.

Answer (score 1):

### Lookup and Copy Rows

- It is assumed that both worksheets are in table format i.e. one row of headers, no empty rows or columns and that the tables are the only thing on each worksheet (UsedRange-related).

```vb
Sub UpdateMaster()
    
    ' If this code is located in any of these workbooks then you shouldn't
    ' use its name but 'ThisWorkbook':
    ' 'Set swb = ThisWorkbook', or 'Set dwb = ThisWorkbook'
    ' Also, you should out-comment the 'Close' line until you are sure
    ' that the code works as expected.
    
    ' Define constants.
     
    Const SRC_WORKBOOK As String = "ExtractFile.xlsm"
    Const SRC_WORKSHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 1
    Const DST_WORKBOOK As String = "Workbook.xlsm"
    Const DST_WORKSHEET As String = "Sheet1"
    Const DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN As Long = 1
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = Workbooks(SRC_WORKBOOK)
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Worksheets(SRC_WORKSHEET)
    
    Dim Data() As Variant, srCount As Long, cCount As Long
    
    With sws.UsedRange ' reference the source (table) range
        srCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' use -1 to exclude headers
        cCount = .Columns.Count
        Data = .Resize(srCount).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook: Set dwb = Workbooks(DST_WORKBOOK)
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = dwb.Worksheets(DST_WORKSHEET)
    
    ' Write the values from the dest. lookup column to the dest. lookup array.
    
    Dim lData() As Variant, dfcell As Range, drCount As Long
    
    With dws.UsedRange
        drCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' use -1 to exclude headers
        Set dfcell = .Cells(1).Offset(drCount + 1)
        lData = .Columns(DST_LOOKUP_COLUMN).Resize(drCount).Offset(1).Value
    End With
    
    ' Write the unique values from the dest. lookup array to a dictionary.
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    Dim dr As Long
    For dr = 1 To drCount
        dict(lData(dr, 1)) = Empty
    Next dr
    
    Erase lData
    dr = 0 ' reset for the next loop
    
    ' Write the not matching values to the top of the array.
    
    Dim sr As Long, c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If Not dict.Exists(Data(sr, SRC_LOOKUP_COLUMN)) Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                Data(dr, c) = Data(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    Set dict = Nothing
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Data had already been updated.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Write the top values from the array to the destination range.

    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dfcell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    drg.Value = Data
    
    dwb.Close SaveChanges:=True

    ' Inform.

    MsgBox "Data updated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```