# is there any way to work faster for Excel VBA Sumifs?

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

i use this type of sumifs like 10 times,
it takes ~3 minutes to calculate.

```
Dim cari_total As Range 'the range i want to sum
Dim Arg1 As Range 'criteria range
Dim Crt1 As Variant 'the criteria

Dim Arg2 As Range 'criteria range

Dim Arg3 As Range 'criteria range
```

I' m using 2 workbooks. "wk" is the 2nd excel file. The other one is "report_4UD.xlsm".

```
'Sum1 and Arg1 must be the same size
Set cari_total = wk.Worksheets(1).Range("H:H")
Set Arg1 = wk.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B")

Set Arg2 = wk.Worksheets(1).Range("N:N")

Set Arg3 = wk.Worksheets(1).Range("C:C")

Windows("report_4UD.xlsm").Activate

Set ws = ActiveSheet
```

This is the loop part.

```
For i = 2 To lRow
    Crt1 = Sheets(1).Range("A" & i)
    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(cari_total, Arg1, Crt1, Arg2, "SBK", Arg3, "0110")
Next
```

Comment: Use array instead of range :), should speed up a bit.

Comment: Do i have to change range' s to variants for arguments?

Comment: Using table formatting allows you to used named ranges, instead of the entire column. So instead of forcing excel to read over 1mil rows, you only force it to check the length of the table.

Comment: Previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64940481#64940481