# Excel VBA Countifs with Loops

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, countif

I'm new to VBA.

I have this formula in Excel in a new column (U) for each row, but takes too long and crashes:

=IF(COUNTIFS($E:$E,E2,$A:$A,"<>"&A2)>0,"Yes","No")

Is there a way to make this in VBA?

Thanks

Comment: Without even knowing the problem: Yes, if it can be done in a formula it can be done in VBA. Aside from the obvious "Yes". Can you explain the formula? To me it looks like it would always be "No". If E is E and A is Not A, "Yes" otherwise "No". But A is always A, so the answer is always "No". OH but you're searching for duplicate Es elsewhere but with different A.

Comment: Limit the range sizes to just the dataset.  Avoid the full column references.  Otherwise see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64940481#64940481

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of your Excel formula. You are trying to put "Yes" in column U for each row where its value in column E is found elsewhere in Column E, but only if the Column A value is different.

Here is how you would do that in VBA:

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Set TargetRange = Sh.Range("A2:E" & LastRow)
    
    Dim vArr() As Variant
    vArr = TargetRange.Value
    
    Dim ColU() As Variant
    ReDim ColU(1 To UBound(vArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
            ColU(i, 1) = "No"
        Dim j As Long
        For j = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
            If vArr(i, 5) = vArr(j, 5) And vArr(i, 1) <> vArr(j, 1) Then
                ColU(i, 1) = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sh.Range("U2").Resize(UBound(vArr, 1)).Value = ColU
End Sub
```

I first take the values of range `A:E` into an array. Then I loop through the array checking if my statement is true. If true, "Yes", otherwise default to "No". And then I output the answers to column U.

The downside to this approach is that it is n^2 number of iterations, as I loop through the array for each row of the array. It will be inevitably slow with a very large dataset.

An improvement suggested by @ChrisNeilsen was to start the inner loop from `i`, cutting the iterations by half. To encorporate this idea, I set up the ColU default values in its own loop first, and then when finding duplicates, I can set both of the duplicates to "Yes" at the same time.

```vb
Sub Example()
    Dim Sh As Worksheet
    Set Sh = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Integer
    LastRow = Sh.Cells(Sh.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Set TargetRange = Sh.Range("A2:E" & LastRow)
    
    Dim vArr() As Variant
    vArr = TargetRange.Value
    
    Dim ColU() As Variant
    ReDim ColU(1 To UBound(vArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
        ColU(i, 1) = "No"
    Next
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1)
        Dim j As Long
        For j = i To UBound(vArr, 1)
            If vArr(i, 5) = vArr(j, 5) And vArr(i, 1) <> vArr(j, 1) Then
                ColU(i, 1) = "Yes"
                ColU(j, 1) = "Yes"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Sh.Range("U2").Resize(UBound(vArr, 1)).Value = ColU
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, thank you for the VBA! It does what I wanted to. Unfortunately, you are also correct with the being slow with very large dataset. Is there a way to optimize? Searching from different articles suggest remove "no" rows.

Comment: Couple of small optimisations:  change to `For f = I To ...`   and add `Exit For` after `ColU(i, 1) = ...`

Comment: @chrisneilsen `Exit For` is a great suggestion, thank you. I think I will also write a second version that can make use of your `For j = i To ...` suggestion

Comment: @toddleson you might be interested in the single loop alternative I just posted

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a double loop (which runs in order n^2) another approach that uses a single loop would be to use a lookup instead of the inner loop (this runs in order n, although a little more complex on each iteration).

Something like

```vb
Sub Example2()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim TargetRange As Range
    Set TargetRange = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 5))
    
    Dim vArr() As Variant
    vArr = TargetRange.Value2
    
    Dim ColU() As Variant
    ReDim ColU(1 To UBound(vArr, 1), 1 To 1)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim rE As Range
    Set rE = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 5), ws.Cells(LastRow, 5))
    
    ColU(UBound(vArr, 1), 1) = "No"
    For i = 1 To UBound(vArr, 1) - 1
        j = 0
        On Error Resume Next
            j = Application.WorksheetFunction.XMatch(vArr(i, 5), rE.Offset(i, 0), 0, 1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        ColU(i, 1) = "No"
        If j > 0 Then
            If vArr(i, 1) <> vArr(j + i, 1) Then
                ColU(i, 1) = "Yes"
                ColU(j + i, 1) = "Yes"
            End If
        End If
    Next
    ws.Range("U2").Resize(UBound(vArr, 1)).Value = ColU
End Sub
```

On my hardware, a arbitary sample data set ran

| Rows | double loop | this code |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.015 | 0.01 |
| 1000 | 0.17 | 0.03 |
| 10000 | 11.9 | 0.33 |
| 50000 | 285.0 | 2.0 |

Comment: I had no idea that a worksheet Match function would be so much faster than an array loop. Great Improvement!

Comment: Important to note though, XMatch is a new function in Excel 365, so this code won't work for older versions of Excel.

Comment: @toddleson I make no apology for using the current version of Excel.  If someone is constrained by using an older version it's up to them to say so. In any case Match will work too, just not quite as fast