# SUMIFS formulas are somewhat slow

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create some sumifs formulas. The raw data has three columns: one for Batch ID, the second for Dates and the third for Amounts. I have used a helper column to get the month and the year in column O (to match them with the headers in another sheet)
Here's my attempt

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sBatchCol As String, sDates As String, sAmount As String, sDateTarget As String, lr As Long, m As Long, c As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        With shPayment
            lr = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            With .Range("O2:O" & lr)
                .Formula = "=""'"" & CHOOSE(MONTH(J2),""Jan"",""Feb"",""Mar"",""Apr"",""May"",""Jun"",""July"",""Aug"",""Sep"",""Oct"",""Nov"",""Dec"")&""-""&YEAR(J2)"
                .Value = .Value
            End With
            sBatchCol = .Range("D2:D" & lr).Address(, , , True)
            sDates = .Range("O2:O" & lr).Address(, , , True)
            sAmount = .Range("K2:K" & lr).Address(, , , True)
        End With
        With shMonthlyFunds
            m = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
            For c = 1 To .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                If .Cells(1, c).Value Like "???-####" Then
                    sDateTarget = .Cells(1, c).Address
                    With .Range(.Cells(2, c), .Cells(m, c))
                    .Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & sAmount & "," & sBatchCol & ",A2," & sDates & "," & sDateTarget & ")"
                    End With
                End If
            Next c
        End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code is working but it is quite slow. I tried to turn off the calculation but the same problem is still there.

Comment: Consider entering the `.Formula` at the end as an array for all cells. That should speed it up considerably.

Comment: Also add `Application.EnableEvents = False` and the start and `True` at the end.

Comment: SUMIFS does tend to be slow.  You can typically use a Dictionary with a composite key (made from the key columns in your IFS) and get better performance.  Works fine as long as you don't need "live" formulas and just the values are OK.  Eg see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64940481#64940481

Comment: @TimWilliams Amazing. The link you posted is wonderful.