# VBA code without using worksheet functions

Tags: vba

Is there any possible way to count and sum without using these codes or other worksheet functions?

```
range("C6").FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(Transaction!C2,Solution1!RC[-1])"
range("D6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Transaction!C2,Solution1!RC2,Transaction!C6)"
range("E6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Transaction!C2,Solution1!RC2,Transaction!C7)"
range("F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIF(Transaction!C2,Solution1!RC2,Transaction!C8)"
```

Comment: Is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72812401/vba-macro-without-using-worksheet-functions?

Comment: It's the same I just simplify the question so it can easily be understand.

Comment: Yes you'd write a loop to go over the data and add the values.  What's wrong with what you currently have?

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams can you give me a sample code using do loop and if function. I just starting to learn VBA and I'm trying to get the result with different approach.

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64939776/faster-way-of-using-sumifs/64940481#64940481

Comment: I think that formula is too complicated for me to understand lol but thanks for this.

Comment: Hello @TimWilliams can you do it with a simple code using do loop and if function that can sum and count my data?